# Prove cis($\theta$) is a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, group-homomorphism

For $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, define cis($\theta$) = $\cos (\theta ) +i\sin (\theta )$

Show cis: $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \left \{ z\in \mathbb{C}:\left | z\right | = 1 \right \}$ is a homomorphism

Show that ker(cis) = $2\pi\mathbb{Z}  = \left \{ 2\pi n\in \mathbb{R}:n\in\mathbb{Z}  \right \}$

I already showed its a homomorphism by:

$$cis(a+b) = cis(a) *cis(b)$$
$$\cos (a+b) +i\sin (a+b ) = (\cos (a) +i\sin (a)) * (\cos (b) +i\sin (b))$$
$$\cos (a+b) +i\sin (a+b ) = [\cos (a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b)] +i[\sin (a)\cos(b)+\sin(b)\cos(a)]$$
$$\cos (a+b) +i\sin (a+b ) = \cos (a+b) +i\sin (a+b )$$
I need help showing the kernal, I'm a bit confused on on how to show 
cis$(2\pi\mathbb{Z}) = e$, $e$ being the identity

Comment: For the kernel, you want to show that if $\theta$ solves $\operatorname{cis}(\theta) = 1$, then $\theta = 2n\pi$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$. The reason is that $1$ is the identity element for the unit circle. To prove this, equate real and imaginary parts.

Comment: That is only *half* the proof-the other half, of course, is showing if $\theta = 2\pi n$, that $\text{cis}(\theta) = 1$ (admittedly, this is the "easy part").

Comment: Do you understand what the identity $e$ is here?

Answer (score 1):

The identity element in $$ \left \{ z\in \mathbb{C}:\left | z\right | = 1 \right \}$$
is $$ z=1=\cos (2k\pi) + i\sin (2k\pi )$$ Therefore the Kernel of $  \mathbb{R}  $ is the set $\{2k\pi\}$ where $k$ is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

For the computation of the kernel, we should solve $$cis(x) = e^{ix} = 1$$

$$\iff \cos(x)+i \sin(x) = 1$$

$$\iff \cos(x)=1 \ \text{and} \ \sin(x) = 0$$

$$\iff \cos(x)=1$$

$$\iff x \in \mathbb Z (2 \pi)$$